# How do I resolve a PHP error "Failed opening required" in a symlink context?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx

I am running Apache/PHP on MacOS X Lion 10.7.4. My directory structure is set up as so:

```
/Users/achan/Sites/
lrwxrwx---   1 achan  staff    23B Apr 27 16:21 epwbst@ -> /Users/achan/dev/epwbst`
```

where `epwbst/` is a symlink inside of `~/Sites`.

If I put `test.php` inside of the `Sites/` directory, Apache serves up the file correctly; it spews out `phpinfo()` like it is supposed to. If I put the same file under the symlink, I get this error:

```
[Mon May 28 14:47:13 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Mon May 28 14:47:13 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/Users/achan/Sites/epwbst/test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Just to be sure that Apache was working, I created a test html file under `~/Sites/epwbst/` and Apache served it up as expected.

**Why can't Apache run php under my symlinked directory?**

I've pasted my php config here: http://pastebin.com/gg27JyVZ

Comment: Could it be a file permissions issue?

Comment: Well, this only occurs with PHP. HTML files are served up fine. Plus, the permissions on the file are world readable and the file contains the simplest of php: `<?php phpinfo()` If it's a file permissions issue, I don't know what to change the file permissions to. We've already established that symlinks 'work' because html can be served from the symlinked folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, this drove me nuts for ***hours***. It ***is*** a permissions issue, but not how one might think. The problem rests with the permissions of the symbolic link itself:

```
/Users/achan/Sites/
lrwxrwx---   1 achan  staff23B Apr 27 16:21 epwbst@ -> /Users/achan/dev/epwbst`
```

Here's the rub: `chmod` won't normally change the permissions on symbolic links, because (with the apparent exception of `php5_module` and some other cases beyond the scope of this answer) those permissions are largely irrelevant as they are ignored in nearly all contexts. Here's the fix:

```
chmod -h 755 /Users/achan/Sites/epwbst
```

Note the `-h`. From the man page:

```
...
-h  If the file is a symbolic link, change the mode of the link itself
rather than the file that the link points to.
...
```

For some reason, `php5_module` actually pays attention to the permissions on the symbolic link. If they are too restrictive, `php5_module` will refuse to see the target, ***even if the `httpd` user could otherwise read and run that very same target using `/usr/bin/php`***.

Consider the following:

```
% umask 027
% cd ~/Sites
% mkdir bar
% chmod 755 bar
% ln -sv bar foo
foo -> bar
% ls -al ~/Sites/foo
lrwxr-x---  1 xyz  xyz  3 Apr 22 13:17 foo -> bar
% ls -adl ~/Sites/foo/.
drwxr-xr-x  2 xyz  xyz  68 Apr 22 13:17 /Users/xyz/Sites/foo/.
% echo 'Hello!' >bar/hello.txt
% chmod 644 bar/hello.txt
% curl http://localhost/~xyz/bar/hello.txt
Hello!
% curl http://localhost/~xyz/foo/hello.txt
Hello!
```

So far, so good. Now consider:

```
% echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' >bar/info.php
% chmod 644 bar/info.php
% curl http://localhost/~xyz/bar/info.php
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
...
</div></body></html>
% curl http://localhost/~xyz/foo/info.php
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/Users/xyz/Sites/foo/info.php' (include_path='.:') in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

Hmmm. My `httpd` runs as user `_www`, so let's check to see if that user can read `.../foo/info.php`:

```
% sudo sudo -u _www cat ~/Sites/foo/info.php
Password:
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Yup. Now let's see if that user can ***run*** `.../foo/info.php`:

```
% sudo sudo -u _www /usr/bin/php ~/Sites/foo/info.php
Password:
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.24
...
If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

Yes?! WTF?! ***Grrr!*** Now repair it:

```
% chmod -h 755 foo
% curl http://localhost/~xyz/foo/info.php
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
...
</div></body></html>
```

[Bang. Done.](http://youtu.be/cCmNYP1k12w)

So, yes. It appears that `php5_module` does something paranoid and nonstandard. This may have gone overlooked as `umask` often defaults to `022`, which will at least create symbolic links with `755`. Also, many filesystems (not HFS+) impose at the kernel level permissions of 777 during symbolic link creation, irrespective of `umask`.

You and I appear to be the two people in the solar system running Apache+PHP on HFS+ while setting our umask to something more restrictive than the default. I'll bet you even use case-sensitive HFS+, too. ;o)

Comment: The many humans outside of this solar system thank you for your answer! :) Within this solar system, though, you'll have to settle for my thanks... :)